# don't understand the pseudocode: (Q[i] = j + r − i) or (Q[i] = j − r + i)

Tags: algorithm

I'm reading Algorithms book "algorithms" (1st edition) by Jeff Erickson.

The book at: https://github.com/jeffgerickson/algorithms/blob/master/1st%20edition/Algorithms-JeffE.pdf

At Figure 2.2 there is pseudocode:

```
PlaceQueens(Q[1 .. n], r):
    if r = n + 1
        print Q[1 .. n]
    else
        for j ← 1 to n
            legal ← True
            for i ← 1 to r − 1
                if (Q[i] = j) or (Q[i] = j + r − i) or (Q[i] = j − r + i)
                    legal ← False
            if legal
                Q[r] ← j
                PlaceQueens(Q[1 .. n], r + 1)    〈〈 Recursion! 〉〉
```

I know(or guess) "(Q[i] = j + r − i) or (Q[i] = j − r + i) " is used to judge whether it is on the diagonal line.

But I don't know how to get Q[i] = j + r − i and Q[i] = j − r + i .

Can I use slope to get Q[i] = j + r − i   (or Q[i] = j − r + i)  relation?

Anyone help?

Comment: Work through it on paper as though you're the computer. Start with i = 1 and work down to r - 1. What are the values that get generated for Q[i] ? Can you mark them on a chessboard layout and see what pattern they make?

Comment: Yes.May be the pattern at Figure 2.3

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that you don't understand what the pseudocode notation there means, or that you don't understand why the algorithm uses the method listed?

Comment: I understand the pseudocode notation,in c programing can write like this: if ( (Q[i] == j) || (Q[i] == j + r − i) || (Q[i] == j − r + i) ). I don't understand why the algorithm uses the method listed,especially how to get Q[i] = j + r − i and Q[i] = j − r + i,can I use slope to get Q[i] = j + r − i  or (Q[i] = j − r + i) relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Q[i] indicates which square in row i contains a queen.`

So we need to check, for each row, if the rows "up and to the left" and "up and to the right" contain queens.

- `j` is the position that we are trying to place a queen (no guarantee that it is legal).
- `r` is the current number of queens that we've placed so far (r = our current queen's row).
- `i` is our iterator that runs through each existing queen's row and checks if our new queen is legal. Note that only this varies for each position that we try.

So each time we want to compute the value that is diagonal to our current queen and see if the other queen is in that column.

Q[i] = j + r − i means
Look at row i (1 through number of queens). Check if that queen is in the column represented by taking our new queen's position (j) and adding (r - i) which is the number of steps "to the right" that we need to take. For example, if we are adding queen number four, we check for a diagonal queen in row one, by stepping up three and over three.

We then do the same, but in the opposite vertical direction (up left) by taking our new queen's position (j) and subtracting (r + i).

I would recommend drawing this algorithm out on paper. Add each queen one by one and track all of the numbers for each step of the algorithm. This should make the algorithm clear.

```
Q = [1, 3]

[
.Q..
...Q
]

say j = 2, r = 2

Trying to add here:
[
.Q..
...Q
..?.
]

i = 0:
  Q[0] == j + r − i -> 2 + 2 - 0 = 4 FALSE
  Q[0] == j - r + i -> 2 - 2 + 0 = 0 FALSE
i = 1
  Q[1] == j + r - i -> 2 + 2 - 1 = 3 TRUE (Q[1] is 3)

This makes sense (there is a Q diagonal to the proposed "?" spot in the image above.
```